# I am getting the error "auth is not a function" when calling my auth function in a route

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, model-view-controller

I have this authenticated function which i want to call whenever a user request sensitive info from the backend. My problem is that everytime I call this function it doesn't run. 
here is my auth function.

```
const auth = (req,res,next)=>{

    try{
        // First get the token.
        const token = req.header("token")
        const verified = jwt.verify(token,process.env.JWT_TOKEN);
        console.log(verified)
        if(!verified){
            return res.status(401).json({
                error : "Token verification failed, auth denied"
            })
        }
        // Add a user to the request, the token will have a id object.
        req.user = verified.id;
        next();
    } catch(err){
        return res.status(400).status({
            error : "something went wrong"
        })
    }
}
```

Here is where I want to call it.

```
const getUserInfo = (req,res)=>{
    db.User.findById(req.user,(error,foundUser)=>{
        if(error) return console.log(error);
        res.json({
            status: 200,
            data: foundUser,
            requestedAt: new Date().toLocaleString()
        });
    });
}
```

I tried running it inside the getUserInfo function but it didnt work. I also tried passing it as a parameter in the getuserinfo function which also didn't work. 
my route is set up like 
`router.get("/user",ctrl.getUserInfo)`

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the error was when you tried calling it inside the `getUserInfo` function?

Comment: @Rodentman87 hey so my issue was that i was exporting an object in the auth file as ```module.exports = { auth }``` that was giving me the ```auth is not a function error```. But when i changed that to module.exports = auth. it worked

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the auth function as a second parameter in router.get("/user",ctrl.getUserInfo) because is a middleware. If you want to know more about it you can read https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

```
router.get("/user", auth ,ctrl.getUserInfo)
```

Comment: I didn't try your way but my issue was that i was exporting a object in the auth file as ```module.exports = { auth }``` that was giving me the auth is not a function error. But when i changed that to module.exports = auth. it worked

Comment: @Adil Khan .. your issue seems to be resolved ..  if the answer worked then please appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

My error stemmed from exporting an object in the auth file instead of a function.   `module.exports = { auth }` was giving me the auth is not a function error. But when i changed that to `module.exports = auth`. it worked